# Access GPS through NDK applications

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am currently building a simple application for Android using the NDK and needs to get
the coordinates from the GPS. I've searched the web, but have come up empty handed. Is there some API or such for NDK-programs to access the GPS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the NDK only supports a limited number of libraries.  It is designed to be used for things that are really processor intensive, and thus would actually benefit from being written in a native language.  From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html), only supported areas:

> - libc (C library) headers
> - libm (math library) headers
> - JNI interface headers
> - libz (Zlib compression) headers
> - liblog (Android logging) header
> - OpenGL ES 1.1 and OpenGL ES 2.0 (3D graphics libraries) headers
> - libjnigraphics (Pixel buffer access) header (for Android 2.2 and above)
> - Minimal set of headers for C++ support

Comment: But ndk support sensor access through android/sensor.h ? so, isn't gps not part of sensor APIs ? I also couldn't find libandroid.so in this list

Answer (score 1):

Your should use JNI wrapper to get GPS coordinates.
NDK does not provide this feature.